# Applying for belgium visa with pregnant wife

Tags: schengen, belgium, pregnancy

I am from India. I am expecting a job offer from a company in Belgium. The company will provide me work permit and help me with the visa process. I have some queries regarding visa process to bring my wife (Indian) along with me. She is pregnant and our baby is due in Feb, 2018. I am expecting an offer in a month or two. Below are my queries:

(1) Should I apply for my wife's visa with me? People mention that it is easier if we apply together. But I am not sure how difficult will that be to take care of my pregnant wife in the Belgium when I am new to the country, no knowledge of regional language and don't know much about medical facilities.

(2) If we apply together say in the month of November (6 month pregnant), what are the chances that they will issue us visa when they know we are expecting a baby soon. Plus, she won't be able to go through x-ray for medical certificate when pregnant.

(3) If we apply together and suppose we both get visas, can she come with the baby after I am settled there? I know it will be painful to get baby's visa afterwards.

(4) If I have to leave her in India for the delivery and apply for her and baby's visa later on, will it be so much difficult to get their visas?

Any help in this regards is highly appreciated.

Comment: Note that contrary to some other countries, Belgium does not grant citizenship to children born in Belgium to recently arrived foreign parents. This is an advantage for you if you end up deciding for your wife to arrive in Belgium before she gives birth, since you can't be suspected of "birth tourism". If your story otherwise checks out and your wife is fit to travel, there should be no reason for the pregnancy to influence the residency decision.

Comment: Be careful to review the restrictions on travel that airlines put on pregnant passengers.